# Need a stored procedure to find missing gaps and insert rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a small dev challenge here. I have the following table `CURR_RATES` in SQL Server:

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES 
(1001300, 'USD', 13, '8/1/2013', 1.31),
(1001301, 'USD', 13, '8/2/2013', 1.32),
(1001302, 'USD', 13, '8/5/2013', 1.33),
(1001303, 'USD', 13, '8/6/2013', 1.34),
(1001304, 'USD', 13, '8/7/2013', 1.35),
(1001305, 'USD', 13, '8/8/2014', 1.31),
(1001306, 'USD', 13, '8/9/2013', 1.32),
(1001307, 'USD', 13, '8/12/2013', 1.33),
(1001308, 'USD', 13, '8/13/2013', 1.34),
(1001309, 'USD', 13, '8/14/2013', 1.35),
(1001310, 'USD', 13, '8/15/2013', 1.36),
(1001311, 'USD', 13, '8/16/2013', 1.37),
(1001312, 'USD', 13, '8/19/2013', 1.38),
(1001313, 'USD', 13, '8/20/2013', 1.38),
(1001314, 'USD', 13, '8/21/2013', 1.37),
(1001315, 'USD', 13, '8/22/2013', 1.36),
(1001316, 'USD', 13, '8/23/2013', 1.35),
(1001317, 'USD', 13, '8/26/2013', 1.34),
(1001318, 'USD', 13, '8/27/2013', 1.33),
(1001319, 'USD', 13, '8/28/2013', 1.31),
(1001320, 'USD', 13, '8/29/2013', 1.32),
(1001321, 'USD', 13, '8/30/2013', 1.33)) as t(DATA_ID, CURR, CODE, [DATE], [RATE])
```

And using a range, for example 2013-08-01 to 2013-08-31, i need to find which days are = to saturday and sunday (weekends). I can easily do this with the datename(dw, CURR_RATES.DATE) function.

```
datename(dw, CURR_RATES.DATE) as weekday from CURR_RATES

DATA_ID     CURR CODE        DATE      RATE  Weekday
----------- ---- ----------- --------- ----- -----------
1001300     USD  13          8/1/2013  1.31  Thursday
1001301     USD  13          8/2/2013  1.32  Friday
1001302     USD  13          8/5/2013  1.33  Monday
1001303     USD  13          8/6/2013  1.34  Tuesday
1001304     USD  13          8/7/2013  1.35  Wednesday
1001305     USD  13          8/8/2014  1.31  Friday
1001306     USD  13          8/9/2013  1.32  Friday
1001307     USD  13          8/12/2013 1.33  Monday
1001308     USD  13          8/13/2013 1.34  Tuesday
1001309     USD  13          8/14/2013 1.35  Wednesday
1001310     USD  13          8/15/2013 1.36  Thursday
1001311     USD  13          8/16/2013 1.37  Friday
1001312     USD  13          8/19/2013 1.38  Monday
1001313     USD  13          8/20/2013 1.38  Tuesday
1001314     USD  13          8/21/2013 1.37  Wednesday
1001315     USD  13          8/22/2013 1.36  Thursday
1001316     USD  13          8/23/2013 1.35  Friday
1001317     USD  13          8/26/2013 1.34  Monday
1001318     USD  13          8/27/2013 1.33  Tuesday
1001319     USD  13          8/28/2013 1.31  Wednesday
1001320     USD  13          8/29/2013 1.32  Thursday
1001321     USD  13          8/30/2013 1.33  Friday
```

What I need to do is write a stored procedure to find the missing Saturdays and Sundays and insert rows for them setting the value of column RATE equal to the previous Friday. The table can contain data from other months so i need to be able to specify a range. Also, the DATA_ID column needs to include a value for the new added rows. For The first inserted row the value of the DATA_ID column should be the value of the last row DATA_ID +1 - The second inserted row should be the DATA_ID of the newly inserted row +1, and so on....so the S.P. needs to figure out the DATA_ID of the last row in the table as well.

Hope this is clear enough - will appreciate any feedback or ideas on how to implement this.

Thank you very much in advance.

R00ty

Comment: Show what you have so far.

Comment: _"equal to the previous Friday"_ even if you're missing a Sunday but _not its corresponding Saturday_?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply! There will always be missing weekends. So for the tables above, Saturday and Sunday need to be inserted both with a value of 1,34. Then after the second Friday, Saturday and Sunday need to be inserted both with a value of 1,32 and so on...

Answer (score 1):

You may need to tinker with the `case` in the `dbo.BuildDateRange` to adjust for how your server is configured (`SET DATEFIRST`)

a function to build a table of all dates between a date range:-

```
create function dbo.BuildDataRange
(
    @StartDate date,
    @EndDate date
)
returns @returntable table
(
    [Date] date,
    PreviousFriday date
)
as
begin
    while @StartDate<=@EndDate begin
        insert into @returntable ([Date],PreviousFriday) 
            values (
                @StartDate,
                dateadd(d,
                    case datepart(dw,@StartDate) 
                        when 1 then -2 
                        when 2 then -3 
                        when 3 then -4 
                        when 4 then -5 
                        when 5 then -6 
                        when 6 then -7 
                        when 7 then -1 
                    end,@StartDate)
                )
        set @StartDate=DATEADD(day,1,@StartDate)
    end
    return
end
go
```

a table of test data:-

```
create table #curr_rates (
    data_id int,
    curr char(3),
    code int,
    [date] datetime,
    rate decimal(10,5)
)
go
```

with some data in it:-

```
insert into #curr_rates values
    (1001299,'usd',13,'2013-07-31',1.25),
    (1001300,'usd',13,'2013-08-01',1.31),
    (1001301,'usd',13,'2013-08-02',1.32),
    (1001302,'usd',13,'2013-08-05',1.33),
    (1001303,'usd',13,'2013-08-06',1.34),
    (1001304,'usd',13,'2013-08-07',1.35),
    (1001305,'usd',13,'2013-08-08',1.31),
    (1001306,'usd',13,'2013-08-09',1.32),
    (1001307,'usd',13,'2013-08-12',1.33),
    (1001308,'usd',13,'2013-08-13',1.34),
    (1001309,'usd',13,'2013-08-14',1.35),
    (1001310,'usd',13,'2013-08-15',1.36),
    (1001311,'usd',13,'2013-08-16',1.37),
    (1001312,'usd',13,'2013-08-19',1.38),
    (1001313,'usd',13,'2013-08-20',1.38),
    (1001314,'usd',13,'2013-08-21',1.37),
    (1001315,'usd',13,'2013-08-22',1.36),
    (1001316,'usd',13,'2013-08-23',1.35),
    (1001317,'usd',13,'2013-08-26',1.34),
    (1001318,'usd',13,'2013-08-27',1.33),
    (1001319,'usd',13,'2013-08-28',1.31),
    (1001320,'usd',13,'2013-08-29',1.32),
    (1001321,'usd',13,'2013-08-30',1.33)
go
```

an SP to insert missing data (will fill any gaps with the previous Fridays rate, so make sure only weekends are missing...

```
create procedure dbo.InsertWeekends
(
    @from date,
    @to date
) as
begin

    declare @watermark int

    select @watermark=max(data_id) 
    from #curr_rates

    insert into #curr_rates
    select @watermark+ROW_NUMBER() over(order by dr.[date]) as data_id,
        cr.curr, 
        cr.code, 
        dr.[date], 
        cr.rate
    from dbo.BuildDataRange(@from,@to) dr
    join #curr_rates cr on cr.date=dr.PreviousFriday
    where not exists(
        select *
        from #curr_rates csq
        where csq.[date]=dr.[Date] 
            and csq.curr=cr.curr 
            and csq.code=cr.code
    )
end
go
```

usage:-

```
exec dbo.InsertWeekends '2013-08-01', '2013-08-31'
go
```

so that this:-

```
select *
from #curr_rates
order by [date]
go
```

produces:-

[image]